# Load XML attributes to c# winform

Tags: c#

I have this xml file which has a structure like this:

```
<MACHINE>
 <CONTROL NAME="" LABEL="TEST1" LABEL1="TEST1"/>
 <CONTROL NAME="" LABEL="TEST2" LABEL1="TEST2"/>
 <CONTROL NAME="" LABEL="TEST3" LABEL1="TEST3"/>
</MACHINE>
```

I need to parse it, then I need to save the data and create multiple textboxes in the form.

I need to use the LABEL as the label and LABEL1 as the name for the textbox

I tried to parse it like this:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(@"C:projects.xml");
XmlNodeList list = xdoc.SelectNodes("//MACHINE");
```

But I have no idea how to go further.

I've added this code to generate some textboxes

```
var n = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            //Create label

            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = String.Format("Label {0}", i);
            //Position label on screen
            label.Left = 10;
            label.Top = (i + 1) * 20;
            //Create textbox
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            //Position textbox on screen
            textBox.Left = 120;
            textBox.Top = (i + 1) * 20;
            //Add controls to form
            label.Name = list[i].Attributes["LABEL"].Value;
            textBox.Name = list[i].Attributes["LABEL1"].Value;
            this.Controls.Add(label);
            this.Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

How can I modify this so it takes as maby values as there are from the XML file rather than just 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml should have proper closing element like.

```
<CONTROL NAME="" LABEL="TEST1" LABEL1="TEST1"></CONTROL>
```

Or

```
<CONTROL NAME="" LABEL="TEST1" LABEL1="TEST1" />
```

You can just select the `CONTROL` instead of the  `MACHINE`. And you can get the count of the `CONTROL` by using [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.count%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Change

```
XmlNodeList list = xdoc.SelectNodes("//MACHINE");
```

Into

```
XmlNodeList list = xdoc.SelectNodes("//CONTROL");
```

Then Set

```
var n = list.Count;
```

Inside the for set the label and textbox name.

```
label.Name = list[i].Attributes["LABEL"].Value;
textBox.Name = list[i].Attributes["LABEL1"].Value;
```

Comment: thank zou very much for the reply, well, i updated it, is it ok? I cannot execute it

Comment: @AniAni, Have you checked the xml string closing element? The `for` syntax seems to be duplicated in your updated question. And change the `//MACHINE` into `//CONTROL` and set the `var n = list.Count;`

Comment: yes thank you i did that, i still get the label name different though, like Label 1, Label 2 and so on, but it counts the rows

Comment: One question please, how do i fill the text box with LABEL1?

Comment: @AniAni, `textBox.Text = list[i].Attributes["LABEL1"].Value;`

Comment: I am inserting this>  textBox.AutoSize = true; but it doesn't work... any idea please?

Comment: @AniAni, there is no [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on `TextBox`

Comment: Ah ok :) sorry, i founf something in the internet and was supposed to be ok . I have one last question if i don't bother you too much, i parse 2 xml files to build 2 win forms, thez are identical in structure but i need to find any new rows and highlight them. Any idea?

Comment: @AniAni, you can filter the list using [**`Except`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [**`Where`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [**`Any`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [**`Contains`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or other [**`Linq Extensions`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckzcawb8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to try out [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
var root = XElement.Load(@"c:\projects.xml");
var controlElements = root.Descendants("CONTROL");

int labelCounter = 1;
foreach (var element in controlElements)
{
    var labelId = (string) element.Attribute("LABEL");
    var textBoxName = (string) element.Attribute("LABEL1");

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = string.Format("Label {0}", labelCounter);

    label.Left = 10;
    label.Top = (labelCounter + 1) * 20;

    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

    textBox.Left = 120;
    textBox.Top = (labelCounter + 1) * 20;

    this.Controls.Add(label);
    this.Controls.Add(textBox);

    labelCounter++;
}
```